# cant get specified axios response value

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, get

So Im trying to print specified value from axios get response but its still undefined

[here is response.data log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j4sy.png)

[and here is specified response.data.id & response.data.ID log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3FI9.png)

why is this happening?

Here is code

```
            const response = await axios.get(`${apiurl}/get/id/${id}`);
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.data.id);
            console.log(response.data.ID);
```

Comment: because `response.data` obviously is an `array`. And an `array` does have neither an `id` nor an `ID` property. Try `response.data[0].ID` instead ...

Comment: Fix your API to not return an array for requests that should only return a single object